# Confusion related to fork return value

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

I was reading about the `fork()` system call and it stated that the return value of `fork()` is 0 for the child process.

My question is what if the there are more than one `fork()` system call in code. Then definitely there will be more than one child process created and they will all have pid = 0.

But the pid is supposed to be unique is it not?

Comment: The child can obtain its pid using the [`getpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `fork` in the parent is the process ID of the newly created process (the child) and in the child is 0, assuming no error.  If there is an error `fork` returns -1 and there is no child.  This is used to easily indicate whether the process after the `fork` is the child or parent as only zero indicates the child (see code below).  The child process ID however is not zero.  The child can obtain its process ID via the function [`getpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html).

```
int res;
if((res = fork())) {
  // In parent, should check if res is -1, if it is fork failed
}
else {
  // In child
}
```